# Inherited Resources and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, inherited-resources

Has anyone had success having Rails 3, [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/) and [Inherited Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) working?  Any tips for making it happen?  I would love to use both gems.

Currently I am running into:

```
undefined method `scoped'
```

On index actions.

Thanks!

---

BTW a workaround for the scoped issue is to override collection like so:

```
class CampaignsController < InheritedResources::Base

  def collection
    @campaigns ||= end_of_association_chain.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end

end
```

But I am looking for a more holistic approach

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using only mongoid, what you should do is to overwrite the default collection behavior in Inherited Resources. The default behavior is this:

https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources/blob/master/lib/inherited_resources/base_helpers.rb#L22-24

That said, the following should do the trick:

```
module MongoidActions
  def collection
    get_collection_ivar || set_collection_ivar(end_of_association_chain.all)
  end
end

InheritedResources::Base.send :include, MongoidActions
```

You can even default the collection to paginate and have pagination for free in all pages.

Comment: Thanks Jose!!  Works great.  I love Inherited Resources, and I was eager to try Mongoid -- glad it was easy to get them to play nice.

Comment: update: this has been incorporated into master by now, right?

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can patch Mongoid:

```
module MongoidScoped
  def scoped
    all
  end
end

Mongoid::Finders.send :include, MongoidScoped
```

This will make `inherit_resources` method work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did to cover both inheriting from `InheritedResources::Base` and using `inherit_resources` statement.

```
module InheritedResources
  module BaseHelpers
    def collection
      get_collection_ivar || set_collection_ivar(end_of_association_chain.all)
    end
  end
end
```

You typically put this into an initializer (I use `config/initializers/mongoid.rb`).

Makes `Mongoid 2.0.0.beta.20` and `inherited_resources 1.2.1` friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Very helpful post !

How would you do this if your controller cannot be subclassed from `InheritedResource::Base` but rather you have to use the class method `inherit_resources`, like so :

```
class MyController < AlreadyInheritedFromController
   inherit_resources
end
```

the above monkey patch does not seem to work in this setup.

It looks like the key might be `InheritedResources::Base.inherit_resources` but i am unclear on the correct way to overwrite this method.  Please correct if i am on the wrong path here.